# Python: recursive generator

Tags: python, recursion, generator

I want to recursively generate all the possible sums of the slices of a string of digits. For example:

```
Input: '891'
Output: 18, 99, 90, 891

In details:
    8+9+1 = 18
    8+91 = 99
    89+1 = 90
    891 = 891
```

However, the code I wrote yields generators of generators:

```
# s: string of digits, c: sum of slices
def rec(s,c):
    for i in range(1,len(s)+1):
        if s=='': yield c
        else: yield rec(s[i:],c+int(s[:i]))
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can sometimes be tricky to get right. But you are confusing yourself by adding the extra argument:

```
def rec(s):
    # No split.
    yield int(s)

    # Split.
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        left = int(s[:i])
        for right in rec(s[i:]):
           yield left + right
```

And indeed:

```
>>> list(rec("891"))
[891, 99, 18, 90]
```

Comment: Upvoted, Would you mind posting some comments on what's happening here?, just for sake of explanation?

Comment: @IronFist It's the same principle as recursion. We assume that `rec(s)` is correct, and ask ourselves how we can build a function that works under that assumption. In this case I know that if I either don't split off anything, or split off 1 part and then combine it with the results from 'the rest', I get what OP asked for.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the combinations and then use `functools.reduce`:

```
def slices(d, c = []):
  if not d:
     yield list(map(int, c))
  else:
     if c:
        yield from slices(d[1:], c[:-1]+[c[-1]+d[0]])
     yield from slices(d[1:], c+[d[0]])
```

---

```
import operator as op, functools
print([functools.reduce(op.add, i) for i in slices('891')][::-1])
#note: printing reverse of list to produce proper order of desired output
```

Output:

```
[18, 99, 90, 891]
```

Answer (score 1):

To yield the elements of a generator instead of the generator itself, use `yield from`:

```
# s: string of digits, c: sum of slices
def rec(s,c):
    for i in range(1,len(s)+1):
        if s=='': yield c
        else: yield from rec(s[i:],c+int(s[:i]))
        #     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The code you posted is still wrong though.